# JW Player Plugin Bug on a Mac in Safari & Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, webforms, safari, jwplayer

I have a video that plays in all browsers on Windows. On a Mac, it fails to play in Safari and Firefox. Here is a screenshot of the console error that it throws in Safari:

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jwplayer("video").setup({ 
    file: "<%= _VideoNode.GetStringValue("YoutubeLink", string.Empty) %>", 
    'controlbar': 'bottom', 
    'height': '360', 
    'width': '640', 
    'skin': '<%= ResolveUrl( "~/App/Styles/video/skin.xml" ) %>' 
     }); 
});
```

and here is a link where you can find a video that uses this code block http://clarkdev.theatomgroup.com/visit/planvisit/guidelines

Comment: This seems to play for me in Firefox. Do you have Flash installed for these browsers? YouTube support in JW Player is really only in Flash mode on desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing flash on the mac solved the problem.  Google Chrome comes with flash built into the browser.